# Balanced line impedance matching

Tags: rf, impedance, impedance-matching

Is there a way to convert a 100Ω balanced connection to a 200Ω balanced connection without using two baluns? I have a 2.4GHz baseband that I want to attach to a front end, but the baseband has a 100Ω balanced connection and the front end has a 200Ω balanced connection. My first thought was to use two baluns to convert to a 50Ω stripline and then back to balanced connection, but I'd like to avoid this if there is a simpler way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can build differential (balanced) matching network, it is a bit more complicated, but general rule is to divide series impedance by 2 (there are 2 series components, one on the positive side, one on the negative side) and multiply shunts by 2 compared to unbalanced Pi or T networks. mind you, component tolerances become very critical as mismatch between the positive and negative lines can cause unwanted spurious emissions, especially with PAs.

Edit:
A tech note from TI http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slwa053b/slwa053b.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Googling a pi network calculator gave me this site:

http://www.changpuak.ch/electronics/calc_18.php

It shows configuration ans values for an L, Pi and T network.

For instance, if I punch in 100ohm, 200ohm and 2400 MHz I get the following values:

[image]

Would that work for you?

Comment: Those are unbalanced filters. Balanced filters have series components also on the negative line.